# Elastic Search curl command not recognised in Windows

Tags: elasticsearch

I downloaded elastic search and ran the elasticsearch.bat on my windows laptop, but as soon as I try:
curl http://localhost:9200
I get:

```
C:\Temp\elasticsearch-6.4.0\bin>curl http://localhost:9200/
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What did I miss? I am following setup instructions as per:
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Also the 'Invok _restMethod' gives error on power shell:

```
PS C:\Temp\elasticsearch-6.4.0\bin> Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:9200
**The term 'Invoke-RestMethod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**
At line:1 char:18
+ Invoke-RestMethod <<<<  http://localhost:9200
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-RestMethod:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is the curl executable location in the PATH variable?

Comment: Because of powershell version. I encountered this issue and according to @Leo Bartkus 's comment I upgrade my powershell and the powershell can recognized the `curl` command.

Answer (score 1):

curl is an separate exe to run, you can download it from the following link
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Or

You can run the elasticsearch using the following command in command prompt

**bin\elasticsearch.bat**

Or

you can install elastic search as service using the following command

**elasticsearch-service.bat install**

ref

https://efficientuser.com/2016/11/01/installing-elasticsearch-5-0-as-service-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at step#3 in the link, after running elasticsearch.bat. I installed curl for windows, still same error. Also the InvokeMethod' does not work, I posted the error.

Comment: I never tried first step. I have used last 2 steps and I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: if you think the answer helps you, please give an upvote

Answer (score 0):

You are on windows, so like the documentation says, use powershell and run this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: It does not work, I uploaded a picture of the error. Thank you. I also installed curl for windows, still did not work.

Comment: Are you using the lastest powershell version? This command works with powershel version 5.1 You can check it with $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Comment: Here's how to solve the problem if you have an old version of powershell. https://codehollow.com/2016/02/invoke-webrequests-via-powershell/